# Retrieving nodes JSON type array

Tags: json, vba, object

Fellow sufferers!

Please see my code. At this point, I have an Object called objJSON. As you can see, it holds nice info. But please help me to get like the info at position 1/Item 1/authorDisplayname, which would be the string "Jens Christian".

Thanks in advance

Peter B Hansen

[Cutout from macro editor Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKmwO.png)

Comment: `Debug.Print objJSON(0).authorUserName`

Comment: The proposed code gives an error. Object doesnt support this property or method.

Comment: It would be helpful to post a small sample of your JSON, and the VBA code you're using.

Comment: Sub TestJSONParsingWithVBACallByName()

    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

    Dim jsonString As String
    jsonString = sRestAntwort

    Dim objJSON As Object
    Set objJSON = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + jsonString + ")")
    
    Debug.Print objJSON(0).authorUserName
    
    'MsgBox (objJSON(0).authorUserName)
End Sub

Comment: I placed the JSON here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3thvJXzChxmWlVvc0NqYm5SR0U

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

'create a js object in the scriptengine
'(loading a sample of your json from a worksheet cell)
oScriptEngine.Eval ("var json=(" + Range("A3").Value + ")")

'query the object properties
Debug.Print oScriptEngine.Eval("json.length")               '>> 3
Debug.Print oScriptEngine.Eval("json[0].authorDisplayName") '>> Peter Bunde Hansen
```

If you're doing any amount of this though, you should consider using something like https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON